# Symfony2 : Automatically map query string in Controller parameter

Tags: symfony

In Symfony2, the route parameters can be automatically map to the controller arguments, eg: http://a.com/test/foo will return "foo"

```
    /**
     * @Route("/test/{name}")
     */
    public function action(Request $request, $name) {
        return new Response(print_r($name, true));
    }
```

see http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/routing.html#route-parameters-and-controller-arguments

But I want to use ***query string*** instead eg: http://a.com/**test?name=foo**

How to do that ?
For me there are only 3 solutions:

- re-implement [ControllerResolverInterface](http://api.symfony.com/2.7/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/Controller/ControllerResolverInterface.html)
- use a custom ParamConverter
- $name = $request->query->get('name');

Is there another solution ?

Answer (score 11):

I provide you the code for those which want to use a converter :

```
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\ParamConverter;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Request\ParamConverter\ParamConverterInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

/**
 * Put specific attribute parameter to query parameters
 */
class QueryStringConverter implements ParamConverterInterface{
    public function supports(ParamConverter $configuration) {
        return 'querystring' == $configuration->getConverter();
    }

    public function apply(Request $request, ParamConverter $configuration) {
        $param = $configuration->getName();
        if (!$request->query->has($param)) {
            return false;
        }
        $value = $request->query->get($param);
        $request->attributes->set($param, $value);
    }
}
```

services.yml :

```
services:
  querystring_paramconverter:
    class: AppBundle\Extension\QueryStringConverter
    tags:
      - { name: request.param_converter, converter: querystring }
```

In your controller:

```
/**
 * @Route("/test")
 * @ParamConverter("name", converter="querystring")
 */
public function action(Request $request, $name) {
  return new Response(print_r($name, true));
}
```

Comment: This is great, but I want to bind the ParamConverter to an attribute/annotation, https://github.com/symfony/symfony/discussions/43960

Answer (score 3):

An improved solution based on Remy's answer which will map the parameter to an entity :

```
<?php
namespace AppBundle\Extension;

use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\ParamConverter;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Request\ParamConverter\DoctrineParamConverter;

/**
 * Put specific attribute parameter to query parameters
 */
class QueryStringConverter extends DoctrineParamConverter {

    protected function getIdentifier(Request $request, $options, $name)
    {
        if ($request->query->has($name)) {
            return $request->query->get($name);
        }

        return false;
    }

}
```

services.yml:

```
services:
  querystring_paramconverter:
    class: MBS\AppBundle\Extension\QueryStringConverter
    arguments: ['@doctrine']
    tags:
      - { name: request.param_converter, converter: querystring }
```

in your controller:

```
/**
 * @Route("/test")
 * @ParamConverter("myobject")
 */
public function action(Request $request, AnyEntity $myobject) {
  return new Response(print_r($myobject->getName(), true));
}
```

Comment: Nice solution, however it breaks functionality of DoctrineParamConverter. I would add `if ($id = parent::getIdentifier($request, $options, $name)) return $id` on top here.

Comment: getIdenfitier is no longer protected method. It's better to extend apply function instead of it.

Comment: Sure. This solution is definitely outdated. But the question was about Symfony 2.

Answer (score 1):

like #2, To solve private method (getIdentifier) first set attributes and execute normally (parent::apply). Tested on Symfony 4.4

```php
<?php

namespace App\FrameworkExtra\Converters;

use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\ParamConverter;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Request\ParamConverter\DoctrineParamConverter;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

class QueryStringEntityConverter extends DoctrineParamConverter 
{
    public function supports(ParamConverter $configuration)
    {
        return 'querystringentity' == $configuration->getConverter();
    }

    public function apply(Request $request, ParamConverter $configuration)
    {
        $param = $configuration->getName();
        if (!$request->query->has($param)) {
            return false;
        }
        $value = $request->query->get($param);
        $request->attributes->set($param, $value);

        return parent::apply($request, $configuration);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Now with **Symfony 6.3** it is possible thanks to query mappers: https://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-6-3-query-parameters-mapper

Answer (score -1):

I havn't checked, but it seems that the FOSRestBundle provides the @QueryParam annotation which does that :
http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/FOSRestBundle/param_fetcher_listener.html