# Can't pass parameters using AJAX + Symfony 4

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, symfony, symfony4

I'm using AJAX to request client names from my DB using autocomplete() inside an input *#descricao*. It requests a route that I created inside Symfony 4 (/acao).
The problem is that I'm trying to set a parameter (/acao?parametro=*clientname*) but I'm get an error:

> Could not resolve argument $parametro of
>   "App\Controller\DefaultController::filter()", maybe you forgot to
>   register the controller as a service or missed tagging it with the
>   "controller.service_arguments"?

I tried to change my routes.yaml:

```
acao:
  path: /acao
  controller: App\Controller\DefaultController::filter
  methods: GET
```

but it didn't work.

script.js:

```
$( "#descricao" ).autocomplete({
        source: function( parametro, response ) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: '/acao',
                    dataType: "json",
                    data: {
                        parametro: $('#descricao').val()
                    },
                    success: function(data) {
                        response(data);
                    }
                });
        }
    });
```

DefaultController:

```
/**
     * @param string $parametro
     * @return JsonResponse
     * @Route("/acao", name="acao", methods="GET")
     */
    public function filter(string $parametro){

        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->getRepository(Clients::class)
            ->createQueryBuilder('c')
            ->andWhere('c.name_fantasy ilike :parametro')
            ->setParameter('parametro','%'.$parametro.'%')
            ->getQuery()
            ->getArrayResult();

        return new JsonResponse($em);
    }
```

What am I doing wrong?

**ANSWER:**

I managed to make it work using POST and changing table name ***c.name_fantasy*** to ***values***:

Controller:

```
/**
     * @param Request $request
     * @return JsonResponse
     * @Route("/acao", name="acao", methods="POST")
     */
    public function filter(Request $request){
        $q = strtoupper(trim($request->request->get('parametro')));

        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->getRepository(Clients::class)
            ->createQueryBuilder('c')->select('c.name_fantasy AS value')
            ->andWhere('c.name_fantasy like :parametro')
            ->setParameter('parametro', '%'.$q.'%')
            ->getQuery()
            ->getArrayResult();

        return new JsonResponse($em);
    }
```

AJAX:

```
$( "#descricao" ).autocomplete({
        source: function( parametro, response ) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: '/acao',
                    dataType: 'json',
                    method: 'POST',
                    data: {
                        parametro: $('#descricao').val()
                    },
                    success: function(data) {
                        if (data.length > 0) {
                            response(data);
                        }
                        else {
                            data = '';
                            response(data)
                        }
                    },

                });
        }
    });
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Symfony2 : Automatically map query string in Controller parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33982299/symfony2-automatically-map-query-string-in-controller-parameter)

Comment: Use `POST` method instead. Change `string $parametro` by `Request $request` and do `$request->request->get('parametro')` to get your parameter.

Comment: sorry, I was completly wrong about GET... Now I updated my answer! This sure will work! (Anyway, Preciel was right...)

Comment: It's working now. I edited my question to add the answer. Thank you!

Comment: Lol, and look, what dumb I am... I add the correct answer, and after, I say: Preciel was right, and I add an up to her comment, while the real point in your question is the difference, between `$request->request` and `$request->query` ... xd (I too much write here when I am tried... in turn some dudes here just attracts scores with fully useless comments and "answers", this is an event here)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, you dont need use routes.yaml for routing, if you use the Route Component:

`Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route`

So just delete that stuff from routes.yaml.

**EDITED:**

```
/**
 * @param Request $request
 * @return JsonResponse
 * @Route("/acao", name="acao", methods="GET", options={"expose"=true})
 */
public function filter(Request $request)
{
    //you should strip and trim the parameter, like (just basic):
    $clientName = strip_tags(
        trim($request->query->get('parametro'))
    );

    // ...
}
```

Where Request is `Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request` <-- you need add to the use statements!

If this not working for you, with your original ajax (what in your question), try on this way:

```
    // ...
    let formData = new FormData();
    formData.append("parametro", $('#descricao').val());

    $.ajax({
        url: '/acao',
        // ...
        data : formData,
        // ...
```

**JUST A TIP:**

I recommend, use the [symfony/bundles/FOSJsRoutingBundle](https://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/FOSJsRoutingBundle/usage.html). You can link your routes in js like this:

```
import Routing from '../../vendor/friendsofsymfony/jsrouting-bundle/Resources/public/js/router';
import Routes from '../../public/assets/js/fos_js_routes.json';

Routing.setRoutingData(Routes);

// ...
    $.ajax({
        //acao is your route name and you route in this case:
        url: Routing.generate("acao"),
```

Dump the latest added routes, with this command:

`php bin/console fos:js-routing:dump --format=json --target=public/assets/js/fos_js_routes.json`

...