# How I can pass an id from one controller to another by redirectToRoute in symfony 3.4?

Tags: symfony

I want to transfer a father id from the Father controller to the mother controller in Symfony by:

```
return $this->redirectToRoute('mother_new', array('id' => $father->getId()));
```

and I will use father id in mother Controller as:

```
public function motherAction(Request $request,Father $father)
```

but this returns the following error:

'Unable to guess how to get a Doctrine instance from the request information for parameter "father". the relation between father and mother is oneToMany.

Please, any one who can help me?

Comment: Can you also add `route` definition for that action?

Comment: Route of mother is: mother_new:
    path:     /register-childby
    defaults: { _controller: "GRBHBundle:Mother:mother" }
    methods:  [GET, POST]                and Route of Father is :father_new:
    path:     /daa'ima galmeessuu
    defaults: { _controller: "GRBHBundle:Father:father" }
    methods: [GET, POST

Comment: Two consideration: you don't have an `id` (representing) `Father` object in the route definition. Is this what you want? I mean, generating that url will append `id` as query string parameter.
If this is itended and you want to have that parameter as query string parameter, I suggest to [create your own converter](https://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/SensioFrameworkExtraBundle/annotations/converters.html#creating-a-converter). You can also [check this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33982299/symfony2-automatically-map-query-string-in-controller-parameter)

Comment: Yes, it is it. I had got my error!

Answer (score 0):

Could you replace this and try?

`public function motherAction(Father $father, Request $request)`

Comment: it has no change. still display "Unable to guess how to get a Doctrine instance from the request information for parameter "father". "

Comment: @simbo could you demonstrate your route definition?

Comment: I'm using yml not annotation and the route of mother is 
   mother_new: path:     /register-childby-mother
    defaults: { _controller: "GRBHBundle:Mother:mother" }
    methods:  [GET, POST]

Comment: Now, I have got my mistake. I did not pass {id} on my route path:/{id}/

Comment: @simbo In fact, for this I wanted to see route defining :)

Comment: child_new:
    path:     /{id}/registerchild
    defaults: { _controller: "GRBHBundle:Father:addChild" }
    methods:  [GET][POST]